# Function omit struct

Tags: c++

it is possible for a function to not have some struct info? Something like this
`int f(int x,int y=1)` and calling f(2) it's just fine but for this `int f(int x,struct my_struct &y)`
what's the correct way considering that it's a reference there?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't understand precisely what you are trying to ask. Are you asking if struct arguments can have default values? Or are you asking if reference arguments can have default values? Or something else?

Comment: Yes. Note that the referred-to question does not have an accepted answer, but the highest voted one is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, actually for both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a non-`const` reference, you can't bind it to a default value which is a temporary object. You *could* bind it to some non-temporary object like so:

```
my_struct obj;
int f(int x, my_struct& y = obj) {
  // ...
}
```

But this would mean that every invocation of `f` without a second argument would have access to the same `obj`. They could each modify it and then the next would receive an `obj` with a different state. This isn't very typical of default values. You expect it to have the same default value each time.

Why would your function take an object by non-`const` reference if it were possible to not pass an object? You take a non-`const` reference when you want the caller to pass an object for you to modify.

It may make more sense for your `y` parameter to be a `const` reference instead. You take a `const` reference when you want the caller to pass you an object for you to observe and you don't want to copy it. Then you *could* bind it to a temporary object like so:

```
int f(int x, const my_struct& y = my_struct(1, 2, "some args")) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @siloan If my answer helped, please say thanks by accepting it! :)

Comment: ups, sorry but i forgot about that, done.